# Python Help: Figuring out what this program can be used for

Tags: python-3.x

So I have a python test coming up (nothing hardcore, it's a beginner type of test) and one of the questions is what the purpose of this is:

```
something = 0
nothing = 0
factor = 1

nothing = int(input("Enter Something:"))

while (nothing > 0):
    if ((nothing % 10) == 1):
        something = something + factor
    nothing = nothing / 10
    factor = factor * 2

print("The something is: ", something)
```

I've been trying to think of answers but I've gotten nowhere. What do you guys think?

Also, I want to know how many times it prints:

```
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(i):
        print(i * j)
```

The answer is 45 (pretty sure), but I want to know why.

Comment: Nobody wants to click on your unknown links, and links can break and invalidate this question and its answers for future users.  Include the relevant code directly in the question.

Answer (score 0):

#### The first post I cannot seem to make sense of.

```
something = 0
nothing = 0
factor = 1

nothing = int(raw_input("Enter Something:"))

while (nothing > 0):
    if ((nothing % 10) == 1):
        something = something + factor
    nothing = nothing / 10
    factor = factor * 2

print('Somtheing is {}'.format(something))
```

If `nothing` is one more than a multiple of 10, then `something` is incremented by 1; `nothing` is divided by 10; it becomes a decimal and will never be 1 more than a multiple of 10, so nothing else happens.

If `nothing` is a power of 10 times one more than a multiple of 10, `something` is incremented by how many powers of ten are multiplied to the number one more than a multiple of 10. Then it reduces to the first case.

For any other cases of `nothing`, `something` will be 0 because `nothing` never is one more than a multiple of 10.

Theoretically this loop would run forever but since computers cannot store extremely tiny values, repeated division yields 0 after some time.

---

The second post is rather straightforward.

```
for i in range(10)
    for j in range(i):
        print(i * j)
```

This indeed does `print` 45 times. When `i = 0` the inner loop runs 0 times; when `i = 1` the inner loop runs once; when `i = 2` the inner loop runs twice; ... when `i = 9` the inner loop runs 9 times. Note that `range(n)` goes *up to but does not equal* `n`. So it runs 9 + 8 + 7 + ... + 2 + 1 + 0 = 45 times.